# video reverse not working in IPad or other real device

Tags: xcode

I tried to make video in reverse.Below links are refered by me

Reverse video demo - https://github.com/mehulparmar4ever/ConvertVideoReverse

but in iPad its take too much time for loading and after loading complete video can not play properly. How to change duration time and frame per second in RCToolbox library? just look my screen shot[image]